# Github ignore all but include one folder

Tags: git, gitignore

In .gitignore file I want to ignored all files and folders excluding only one folder.
I try something like this but no success.

```
 # Ignore everything:
/**

# Except for :
!/charts/
```

Any suggestions?
Thanks

Comment: just put the path of the files or directories that you want to ignore in `.gitignore` for example a file name `style.css` you can write it in git ignore as `path/to/file/style.css` for directories you can use special characters for example we want to ignore `/css` fire directory , it be like `path/to/file/css/*`and this ignore all the files that css directory contain

Comment: `/**` is a recursive wildcard, `!/charts/` matches only the folder name. So `charts` won't be ignored, but everything in it will. `git check-ignore -vn somepath` will tell you what pattern if any decides whether somepath is ignored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To ignore everything you should use: *. Like this:

```
# ignore everything:
*

# except:
!charts/
!charts/*
```

You should keep excepting all directories under charts/*/...

Answer (score 2):

`/**` is a recursive wildcard, `!/charts/` matches only the directory name. So charts won't be ignored, but everything in it will. `git check-ignore -vn somepath` will tell you what pattern, if any, from what line in what file, decides whether `somepath` is ignored, a no-match will show up as `:: somepath`,